# How to club child elements inside the same div tag together in CSS?

Tags: python, html, selenium, css-selectors

I am trying to create a list of topics associated with each quote and author from https://www.brainyquote.com/quote_of_the_dayhttps://www.brainyquote.com/quote_of_the_day using Selenium.

At present, since every quote has exactly 4 topics each, I was able to make do like so:

```
total_topics = [topic.text for topic in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("""div.col-xs-4.col-md-4 a.qkw-btn.btn.btn-xs.oncl_list_kc""")] 
    grouped_topics = [] 
    for i in range( int(len(total_topics)/4) ):
        grouped_topics.append(total_topics[4*i:4*i+4])
```

The problem is that a case could be there where there are less or more than 4 topics per quote, wherein this program will fail. 
The HTML code on the website for the topics sub-section is:

```
<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
 <div class="qotd-q-cntr">
  <div class="m-brick grid-item boxy bqQt">
   <div class="qll-bg">
    <h2 class="qotd-h2">Quote of the Day</h2>
    <div class="qll-dsk-kw-box">
     <div class="kw-box">
      <a href="/topics/life-quotes" class="qkw-btn btn btn-xs oncl_list_kc" data-idx="0">Life</a>
      <a href="/topics/you-quotes" class="qkw-btn btn btn-xs oncl_list_kc" data-idx="1">You</a>
      <a href="/topics/purpose-quotes" class="qkw-btn btn btn-xs oncl_list_kc" data-idx="2">Purpose</a>
      <a href="/topics/alive-quotes" class="qkw-btn btn btn-xs oncl_list_kc" data-idx="3">Alive</a>
```

How do I club all the anchor tag texts inside the same div tag? Hope I was able to deliver my point home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the search to two, locate the container of the subjects and than the subjects

```
grouped_topics = []
quotes = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.col-xs-4.col-md-4 div.qll-dsk-kw-box')
for quote in quotes:
    topics = quote.find_elements_by_css_selector('a.qkw-btn.btn.btn-xs.oncl_list_kc')
    grouped_topics.append([topic.text for topic in topics])
```

Comment: I had no idea we could do nested searching of elements like that! Always thought only ```driver``` could be used to access elements.

Comment: @ChaoSAdm [webelement](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html) has the `find_element_by_*` methods as well. In Java you will see it implements `SearchContext` which provide the search capability.